# Android Fused Location Provider with disabled location services

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I implemented the fused location provider in an app. When I start the app with disabled location services, connect failes correctly and the appropriate error dialog is shown, based on the code examples from Google. When I now leave the app and re-enter it, connect() is called again. Even though the location services are still disabled, the onConnected() callback method is invoked and not the onConnectionFailed() callback. Has anyone seen this as well and found a solution to this? Even creating a new LocationClient on restart does not help. As long as the app has just been sent to background and not really closed (with finish() of the running activity), I don't get the message again.

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed a strange behavior, I can suggest a different method for checking coarse location availability, try the following:

```
public boolean isCoarseLocationEnabled(Context context){
if (context() != null) 
{
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

it will return true if coarse location is available and false otherwise.